# Idiom for getting richer

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

In French there's a saying *mettre un peu de beurre dans les épinards* which, literally translated, means *to put some butter in the spinach*. It's an idiom that describes money improving one's situation.

What idioms in English are there that describe this?

For example, *greasing one's pockets* can be interpreted as improving someone else's situation, but it wouldn't be used in a sentence like *winning this bonus will ????????? and make you richer*.

Comment: It's more about being ***less poor*** rather than ***more rich***, but you could certainly say *Winning this bonus will **keep the wolf from the door***.

Answer (score 1):

**From rags to riches (phrase):** Used to describe a person's rise from a state of extreme poverty to one of great wealth — [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/rags_to_riches)

**Example:**

How did he move from rags to riches almost overnight?

---

**Be on the way up:** To be rising to a higher level or a better position — [Macmillan dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/amp/dictionary/british/be-on-the-way-up)

**Examples:**

- Prices are on the way up.
- This city is clearly on the way up.
- She is definitely on the way up and could become CEO before too long.

Alternatively,

**Go/come/move up in the world:**
To have more money or a better social position than you had before — [CED](http://www.dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/go-come-up-in-the-world)

**Example:** Roger and Ann have gone up in the world - these days they only ever travel first-class.

Answer (score 1):

Winning this bonus will fatten your bank account and make you richer.

Winning this bonus will sweeten things for you and make you richer.

Winning this bonus will make you richer.